# Ignore certain chrachters while searching

Tags: sqlite, search

I want to search for specific string in some Arabic text which contains characters such as ُ  ّ  َ  ِ . How can I force SQLite to ignore these characters while searching?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm used to compare values is called a [collation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation).

SQLite's C API allows you to [define a new collation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html).

If you are using SQLite from a language or framework that does not expose this API (such as Android), you could change your database to store a normalized  copy of these text values, without these characters.